# How to obtain the object corresponding to a given singleton (or eigen) class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

Suppose the following code:

```
class A
end

a = A.new

As = class << a
    self
end

# or:
# As = a.singleton_class
```

Is there some way to get `a` from `As`?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing there, but I'm almost sure that it's terribly wrong way to achieve the result. What is it that you're ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Just learning about the dark corners of Ruby. Not trying to solve any practical problems.

Comment: Well, in that case, forget what you saw here and never ever do it in a real project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simple:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(As).first
# => #<A:0x000000029a7c50>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trick for you:

```
class A
end

a = A.new

As = a.singleton_class

a2 = ObjectSpace.each_object.select{|obj| obj.singleton_class == As}.first

a2 == a # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just educated guessification on my part so YMMV, but I think "a" needs to be defined as a class variable (ie. "@@a = A.new") and then you would have the appropriate accessor method to return the class instance.

That being said, however, have you considered using the [Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) module (assuming you're on 1.9.3)?

Comment: I'm talking about Ruby eigenclasses, also known as singleton classes, confusingly. This question is not about the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by [sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314166/sawa) does not work for eigenclasses of classes. A universal method can be obtained via `Object#to_s` and `Module#to_s` methods, by parsing the returned string, see [atalon.cz](http://atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/#object-to-string-map-tos). However, this solution is not 100% reliable, because in Ruby, constants can be reassigned / deleted.